# a = b. Altering b doesn't alter a

Tags: python

```
input1 = input()

a = None
b = None

if input1 == "Bleeb":
    a = 1
    b = a

if a == 1:
    a = 2

print(a)
print(b)
```

```
2
1
```

is what's printed

a and b are made equivalent - There is made to be no difference between them, they're made to be just different ways of writing/representing the same thing.

Yet editing a (in the second if statement) does not edit b.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You _can't_ fix it. `b = a` points both names to the same value, `1`, then `a = 2` changes where `a` is pointed but doesn't alter where `b` is pointed. Recommended reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html, and/or run it in https://pythontutor.com/.

Comment: You are mis-interpreting how Python works, **names** are assigned to objects rather than names 'holding' object values.

Comment: *"a and b are made equivalent"* – no, the value of `a` has been assigned to `b`. The `=` operator in Python is used for assignment. It's different from arithmetics where symbol `=` is used in equations to annotate equivalence.

Comment: `b = a` This is a one-time assignment; it is not an ongoing formula or permanent relationship, as you seem to expect.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a visualisation of what your code does:

After the input, it assigns `None` to both `a` and `b`:

```
a: ─┐    2
    │    1 
b: ─┴──► None
```

The values 1 and 2 are depicted here because the come into play later in the program.

When the first `if` condition is True, we assign 1 to `a`, which means it no longer references the same value as `b`:

```
a: ─┐    2
    └──► 1 
b: ────► None
```

Then `b = a` is executed, and so both reference the same value again

```
a: ─┐    2
    ├──► 1
b: ─┘    None
```

The second `if` block enters where `a` is assigned 2. Just like the earlier assignment to `a`, this results in a situation where `a` and `b` no longer reference the same value:

```
a: ────► 2
    ┌──► 1
b: ─┘    None
```

#### A solution: objects that *contain* the intended value

If `a` and `b` reference objects that can be mutated, then you could store the intended value in an object *attribute*, or *index*. Here is how it could work with lists:

```
input1 = input()

a = None
b = None

if input1 == "Bleeb":
    a = [1]  # Note that A now references a list containing the value
    b = a    # B references the same list

if a and a[0] == 1:  # Look at the contained value when a is no longer None
    a[0] = 2   # A doesn't get a different reference, but its element does
 
print(a)  # [2]
print(b)  # [2]  -- the same list
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong in the interpreter's behavior
After the first assignemnt b = a, the name b has nothing to do with the name a anymore.
So changing a won't change the value of b.

The following code will display it

```
input1 = "Bleeb"

a = None
b = None

if input1 == "Bleeb":
    a = 1
    b = a

print("Id of a is: ", id(a))
print("Id of b is: ", id(b))

if a == 1:
    a = 2
    
print("Id of a is: ", id(a))
print("Id of b is: ", id(b))

print(a)
print(b)
```

Look at the output to see completely new object

```
Id of a is:  134928572468136
Id of b is:  134928572468136
Id of a is:  134928572468168
Id of b is:  134928572468136
2
1
```

Answer (score -1):

Mathematically what you are saying makes complete sense.
But in computer programming we assume the statement a=b as saying "assign the value of RHS(b) to LHS(a) and that's it only a one time event.

If you want them to always have the same value you might need a loop saying
if a != b then a=b and b=a
the will ensure that when ever u change a or b the change will be transferred